# Magento 2.3.5 - Change Date Format on item options in Sales Order details

Tags: magento2.3, orders, sales-order

**UPDATE**

I have created a product with custom options like below. One of the fields is a date field. I have modified the date option (date.phtml) to show the time choice on the date-picker. However, because the option is declared as a date not showing the time in the dashboard by default.

[image: Pick-up Date-Time Option]

When a customer place an order the date appears without the time details like below.

[image: Missing Time in order details]

How could I change the date format to display the time on items options in order details? I don't want to use the default time option of Magento because doesn't allow us to set restrictions. I want to have an option with DateTime picker.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:-

```
$date = $this->_localeDate->date(new \DateTime($yourDate))->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Could you please provide me with more details where to apply the change?

Comment: Is this a third-party module ???